# Maximum amount of data that R igraph package can handle

Tags: r, igraph

I'd like to ask what is the maximum amount of data R igraph package can handle. Is it possible to write hunderds of million rows of data? I could not find anything specific on the document. The document says that it can handle huge amounts of data.

Thanks

Comment: igraph deals with graphs, not tables, so there are no "rows".

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, R/igraph does not check if graph size limits are exceeded, however, if you do exceed certain values, it may misbehave. Checks will hopefully be added for version 2.0.

To be on the safe side, follow these guidelines:

- Avoid vectors or matrices with more than `2^31 - 1` ~ 2.1 billion elements. That refers to the total number of elements in the matrix, i.e. a square matrix should not be larger than 46340 by 46340.
- Graphs should have fewer than `2^31 - 1` ~ 2.1 billion vertices.
- Graphs should have fewer than `2^30 - 1` ~ 1 billion edges.

These are likely to remain the size limits for version 2.0 of R/igraph, except that when they are exceeded, a user-friendly error will be shown. The reason for these limits is that R still does not support 64-bit integers.

The C, Python and Mathematica interfaces of igraph will be able to handle much larger graphs as they will be using 64-bit integers on systems that support it.